# Can I remove parent window when opening a new window?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, infragistics

I'm having an issue with a our main application's window activating itself when the mouse is hovered over it.

I'm opening the new window in a javascript function using the line below:

```
window.open(URL, 'Requests', 'location=no,toolbar=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
```

I have noticed that if I open a new IE window through Explorer, hovering over our main application's window does not reactivate itself. Even in this case though, the main window does make itself be "on top" of the pop-up window created by the window.open command above.

The question is this: **Is there any way, when opening a "child" window in javascript, to detach the child window from the parent?**

Further info: I am using an Infragistics WebDataMenu with ActivateOnHover set to true so users don't need to click on main menu items to see sub-menu choices. Unfortunately, that setting sensitizes the whole menu bar so that sliding the mouse through it activates the menu (and sadly the window when a popup is active). This is the root behavior I'm trying to fix.

Comment: I am not sure how much you can control this because I get different behavior using the same code opening a page in the same site and another website: window.open("Default2.aspx");
window.open("http://www.infragistics.com");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I gave up on making this work. I found that what I had to do was turn off ActivateOnHover from the WebDataMenu, which didn't answer this question and requires users to click on the menu to make it drop down, but it became a work-around.

Answer (score 2):

The `window.open();` method will create a popup window that really only shares a relationship through JavaScript via the return value of the call, and the `window.opener` property on the popup window.

What you want is the behavior of a modal window that locks out interaction from the 'parent' page while you work on the 'child' popup.

You can try to fight with JavaScript (and your users) by forcing a focus on the popup and blocking any blurring but this will drive users nuts when they want to go read their email etc. (eg not recommended)

You can also use the not so standard showModalDialog(); method but support is far from fully cross browser and there are a whole bunch of new problems if you try to use this (no right click in IE, zoom issues in IE, and no grandchildren popups to name a few) (again not recommended)

What you can do is make an "overlay" popup similar to many online photo viewers where you first overlay a mask (typically semi transparent) that blocks mouse/focus on the entire page content below and then overlay that with your "popup content". Just be sure that you provide a close option that removes the mask when the overlay is closed/done.

Note if you need to support IE6 you'll also need an iframe shim (Google if needed)

Many UI frameworks will provide a "dialog" just like this for you. (Eg jQueryUI)

Comment: @Dan As you are using NetAdvantage already, you could use the WebDialogWindow to provide your dialog window if you use this approach: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WebDialogWindow_About_WebDialogWindow.html